# docker container is not accessible from other machines on host's network

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, portforwarding

I was doing some devops and writing a script to turn my current host/nginx server/nginx setup into a host/docker/nginx server/docker/nginx set up so I can keep directories and etc the same between them.

The problem is that any ports I expose on a docker container are only accessible on the host and not from any other machines on the host network.

When typing 192.168.0.2 from a machine such as 192.168.0.3 it just says took too long to respond, but typing 192.168.0.2 from 192.168.0.2 will bring up the welcome to nginx page?! The interesting part is I did a wireshark analysis on en0 on port 80 and there are actually some packets coming through

See pastebins of packet inspections:
LAN to docker: https://pastebin.com/4qR2d1GV
Host to docker: https://pastebin.com/Wbng9nDB

I've tried using `docker run -p 80:80 nginx/nginx` and `docker run -p 192.168.0.2:80:80 nginx/nginx` and `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 nginx/nginx` but this doesn't seem to fix anything.

Should see welcome to nginx when connecting from 192.168.0.3 to 192.168.0.2.

this is in my dev environment which is an osx 10.13.5 system.

when I push this to my ubuntu 16.04 server it works just fine with the containerized nginx accessible from the www and when I run ngnix on my host without docker I can connect from external machines on the network too

Comment: sounds like a network-problem not a docker-problem. This can maybe a firewall setting or system settings or something else... 
If the container is accessible on your `localhost` outside the container there must be a connection problem.

Comment: @Wie the thing is that I can connect when I run nginx on its own and not in a docker container, so, makes absolutely no sense right? I even allowed the docker program through my osx firewall

Comment: You were doing some _what_?

Comment: @CashIsClay what?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit confusing the 127.0.0.1 within the port line will bind it to localhost only - you won't be able to access the docker from another machine. Remove the IP address and you should be able to access the docker from outside localhost.

Comment: what I meant was I've tried using those variants on top of just `-p 80:80` which is the equivalent to `-p 0.0.0.0:80:80` as I'm sure you know

Comment: I thought maybe there was some weird thing happening that's why I tried `192.168.0.2:80:80` because the packets were getting through just not forwarded to the container apparently...